# Web part custom properties Issues

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have one webpart with custom properties and i want to use the same webpart more than one time on the same  page ( or others ) just setting different values to the properties.

But when I insert the webpart a second time on page, the new settings override the first webpart i already inserted.

Here is my code:

```
public enum LinkEnum { QuickLinks, CriticalLinks, ExternalLinks };
        public static LinkEnum typeLink;
        [Category("Extended Settings"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Link Types"),
        WebDescription("Please Choose a type of link")]
        public LinkEnum TypeLink
        {
            get { return typeLink; }
            set { typeLink = value; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you marked that field as `static`; remove that and you will be good to go